# How to extend SNMP with a python script

Tags: raspberry-pi, snmp, net-snmp

I would like to set a value defined in the Python script to an OID. However, when I execute my script. The message appears. That this OID does not exist. Later it is intended that the data will be displayed in real time using a DHT11 sensor. First, however, I wanted to familiarize myself with SNMP and thus output the value manually.

**Python File**

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *

def set_snmp_value(oid, value):
    """
    Setzt einen SNMP-Wert auf einen bestimmten Wert.
    :param oid: Die OID des SNMP-Wertes, der gesetzt werden soll.
    :param value: Der Wert, der gesetzt werden soll.
    """
    iterator = setCmd(
        SnmpEngine(),
        CommunityData('public', mpModel=0),  # 'public' ist die Community-String. Passen Sie dies an Ihre Konfiguration an.
        UdpTransportTarget(('localhost', 161)),  # 'localhost' und 161 sind die Standard-IP und der Port des SNMP-Agents.
        ContextData(),
        ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(oid), Integer32(value))
    )

    errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(iterator)

    if errorIndication:
        print(errorIndication)
    elif errorStatus:
        print('%s bei %s' % (errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                            errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex) - 1][0] or '?'))
    else:
        for varBind in varBinds:
            print('Erfolg:', varBind)

# Beispiel: Setzt den Wert der OID '1.3.6.1.4.1.1.2' auf 5
set_snmp_value('1.3.6.1.4.1.1.2', 5)
```

**MIB-File**

```
DHT11-MIB DEFINITIONS ::= BEGIN

IMPORTS
    MODULE-IDENTITY, OBJECT-TYPE, Integer32, enterprises
    FROM SNMPv2-SMI;

dht11MIB MODULE-IDENTITY
    LAST-UPDATED "202401040000Z"
    ORGANIZATION "Ihre Organisation"
    CONTACT-INFO "Ihre Kontaktinformationen"
    DESCRIPTION
        "Eine MIB-Modul zur Darstellung von DHT11 Sensorwerten."
    ::= { enterprises 1 }

-- Hier definieren wir ein neues Objekt für den Sensorwert
dht11SensorValue OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX Integer32
    MAX-ACCESS read-only
    STATUS current
    DESCRIPTION
        "Der Wert des DHT11-Sensors, der vom Python-Skript bereitgestellt wird."
    ::= { dht11MIB 2 }

END
```

**SNMP Config**

```
###########################################################################
#
# snmpd.conf
# An example configuration file for configuring the Net-SNMP agent ('snmpd')
# See snmpd.conf(5) man page for details
#
###########################################################################
# SECTION: System Information Setup
#

# syslocation: The [typically physical] location of the system.
#   Note that setting this value here means that when trying to
#   perform an snmp SET operation to the sysLocation.0 variable will make
#   the agent return the "notWritable" error code.  IE, including
#   this token in the snmpd.conf file will disable write access to
#   the variable.
#   arguments:  location_string
sysLocation    Sitting on the Dock of the Bay
sysContact     Me <me@example.org>

# sysservices: The proper value for the sysServices object.
#   arguments:  sysservices_number
sysServices    72

pass .1.3.6.1.4.1.1.2 /usr/bin/python /home/pi/Temperatur/test.py

###########################################################################
# SECTION: Agent Operating Mode
#
#   This section defines how the agent will operate when it
#   is running.

# master: Should the agent operate as a master agent or not.
#   Currently, the only supported master agent type for this token
#   is "agentx".
#   
#   arguments: (on|yes|agentx|all|off|no)

master  agentx
# agentaddress: The IP address and port number that the agent will listen on.
#   By default the agent listens to any and all traffic from any
#   interface on the default SNMP port (161).  This allows you to
#   specify which address, interface, transport type and port(s) that you
#   want the agent to listen on.  Multiple definitions of this token
#   are concatenated together (using ':'s).
#   arguments: [transport:]port[@interface/address],...

agentaddress  0.0.0.0



###########################################################################
# SECTION: Access Control Setup
#
#   This section defines who is allowed to talk to your running
#   snmp agent.

# Views 
#   arguments viewname included [oid]

#  system + hrSystem groups only
view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.1
view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1


# rocommunity: a SNMPv1/SNMPv2c read-only access community name
#   arguments:  community [default|hostname|network/bits] [oid | -V view]

# Read-only access to everyone to the systemonly view
rocommunity  public default -V systemonly
rocommunity6 public default -V systemonly

# SNMPv3 doesn't use communities, but users with (optionally) an
# authentication and encryption string. This user needs to be created
# with what they can view with rouser/rwuser lines in this file.
#
# createUser username (MD5|SHA|SHA-512|SHA-384|SHA-256|SHA-224) authpassphrase [DES|AES] [privpassphrase]
# e.g.
# createuser authPrivUser SHA-512 myauthphrase AES myprivphrase
#
# This should be put into /var/lib/snmp/snmpd.conf 
#
# rouser: a SNMPv3 read-only access username
#    arguments: username [noauth|auth|priv [OID | -V VIEW [CONTEXT]]]
rouser authPrivUser authpriv -V systemonly
```

I integrated the MIB file into the SnmpB tool from another device and the folder structure was displayed